# Copying a folder using xargs

Tags: linux, cp, xargs

A command gives me the path of a folder. I want to copy the content of this folder to the current working directory.

What I tried so far is

```
bundle show minima  | xargs -I{}  cp -r {} ./
```

where `bundle show minima` returns the path of the folder which content I want to copy. However, this copies the whole folder. How can I copy only the folder's content?

Comment: is the `bundle show minima` folder name?

Comment: No, it is a commad returning the path. In my case it returns `/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-2.1.1/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
bundle show minima  | xargs -I{}  cp -r {}/* ./
```

but you will miss hidden files (beginning with ".")

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still does not work for me. I get the error `cp: cannot stat '/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-2.1.1/*': No such file or directory`.

Comment: I just figured out that replacing `*` with `.` seems to work.